# Angular NullInjector for Location when using providedIn: platform

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a strange problem. I am working on a library that is imported into my project where I have a service specified as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'platform'
})
export class MyService {}
```

However when I import this into my project, I get a NullInjector error for Location.

If I change the Injectable to providedIn: 'root', then I get a NullInjector for MyService.

Does anyone know how I can use providedIn: 'platform' and still be able to inject Location?

I've tried adding Location to the app module and it made no difference.

Comment: Did you try using provider at the component or module level  ? ex. prividers: [MyService]

Comment: Thank you for the input. In my case it turned out to be a bad import in the receiving project. Once I imported it properly, I was able to revert MyService back to providedIn: 'root' and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not properly importing MyService in the project that was receiving it. providedIn: 'platform' simply masked the wider issue.

Once I imported it in imports: [] I was able to revert all the providedIns back to 'root' and the problem is gone.